Not able to stop docker from using cached resources
I have a nextjs react app, which runs in a docker container. It was working few days back now I see a random docker build error
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 9125c105-47b0-4d56-8450-36f7dd9aa68d::2kg5012vpvayjscu47vims02t: "/app/.next/static": not found
The issue i see here is docker keeps using cached resources for everything from copying source files (even though i changed them) to npm installs and builds
Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV APP_ENV production
ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm ci --omit=dev
RUN npm run build

COPY /app/.next/standalone /app
COPY /app/public /app/public
COPY /app/.next/static /app/.next/static

# CMD ["/app/scripts/run.sh"]
CMD ["node", "/app/server.js"]

Buildlog
➜  repo git:(main) ✗ PROGRESS_NO_TRUNC=1 docker build --no-cache --progress plain -t tmp:tmp .
#0 building with "desktop-linux" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 366B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:22-alpine
#2 DONE 0.4s

#3 [internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:22-alpine@sha256:415f3219943ef82fa45988acdaa7df05a0b52cabd3502095c59d34cbe28c1bc1
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [2/8] WORKDIR /app
#5 CACHED

#6 [internal] load build context
#6 transferring context: 59.52kB 0.0s done
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [5/8] RUN npm run build
#7 CACHED

#8 [4/8] RUN npm ci --omit=dev
#8 CACHED

#9 [8/8] COPY /app/.next/static /app/.next/static
#9 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 9125c105-47b0-4d56-8450-36f7dd9aa68d::knwbuedqsipon8v7qwkk9a6pn: "/app/.next/static": not found

#10 [7/8] COPY /app/public /app/public
#10 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 9125c105-47b0-4d56-8450-36f7dd9aa68d::knwbuedqsipon8v7qwkk9a6pn: "/app/public": not found

#11 [6/8] COPY /app/.next/standalone /app
#11 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 9125c105-47b0-4d56-8450-36f7dd9aa68d::knwbuedqsipon8v7qwkk9a6pn: "/app/.next/standalone": not found

#12 [3/8] COPY . .
#12 CANCELED
------
 > [6/8] COPY /app/.next/standalone /app:
------
------
 > [7/8] COPY /app/public /app/public:
------
------
 > [8/8] COPY /app/.next/static /app/.next/static:
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     COPY /app/.next/standalone /app
  14 |     COPY /app/public /app/public
  15 | >>> COPY /app/.next/static /app/.next/static
  16 |     
  17 |     # CMD ["/app/scripts/run.sh"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 9125c105-47b0-4d56-8450-36f7dd9aa68d::knwbuedqsipon8v7qwkk9a6pn: "/app/.next/static": not found

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/vtugiztotdf5bm7ygu9ecc06u

There is no dockerignore file and have already tried running docker system prune -a

That error message says there's no ./app/.next/static directory, on the host system, relative to the current directory (the last argument to docker build).  Does that directory exist?  Why do you believe there's a caching problem?  (You COPY . . the entire build context into the image a couple lines above; do you need additional COPY lines later?)

the files that I copy do no include node_modules or .next folder they should get created when the install and build commands are run but at #7 [5/8] RUN npm run build
#7 CACHED
#8 [4/8] RUN npm ci --omit=dev
#8 CACHED
it is always taking from cache which is the issue here

If nothing in the build context has changed, why should the RUN commands produce different output?  Why do you believe that cached output is a problem?

(There is a docker build --no-cache option, but you almost never need it, and it won't solve the problem of the following COPY line failing.)

I have changed the source files multiple times it still keeps taking cached
